Pushforward of vector field and its divergence
Let $X:U_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth vector field defined in an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\phi:U_1\rightarrow U_2$ a diffeomorphism between open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Let $Y = \phi_*X$, ie,
$$Y(p) = d\phi_{\phi^{-1}(p)}(X(\phi^{-1}(p))),\qquad  p \in U_2.$$
Here, we are considering that if $X(x,y) = (P(x,y), Q(x,y))$, where $P:U_1 \to \Bbb{R}$ and $Q:U_1\to \Bbb{R}$ are smooth functions, then
$$
\operatorname{div}(X) := \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} 
+ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}.
$$
Is there any relation between $\operatorname{div}(X)$ and $\operatorname{div}(Y)$? Can I get $\operatorname{div}(Y)$ in terms of $\phi$ and $\operatorname{div}$?

To take some of the flamboyance out of the expression $$d\phi_{\phi^{-1}(p)}(X(\phi^{-1}(p)))$$ the most obvious choice of a concrete $\phi$ you could study is the coordinate transformation from polar to Cartesian. It is easy to derive the divergence of $Y$ in polar coordinates and you can check your results in a lot of MSE posts.

Recall the given a volume $\mu$, the divergence of a vector field $X$ with respect to $\mu$ is characterized by
$$\mathcal L_X \mu = (\operatorname{div} X) \mu .$$
Now, suppose $\phi : M \to N$ is (local) map between manifolds equipped respectively with volume forms $\mu, \nu$, so that we can identify $\det \phi$ with a scalar function on $M$ characterized by $\phi^* \nu = (\det \phi) \mu$. Then
\begin{align*}
\phi^* ((\operatorname{div} Y) \nu)
&= \phi^* (\mathcal L_Y \nu) \\
&= \phi^* (\mathcal L_{\phi_* X} \nu) \\
&= \mathcal L_X (\phi^* \nu) \\
&= \mathcal L_X ((\det \phi) \mu) \\
&= (\det \phi) \mathcal L_X \mu + (X \cdot \det \phi) \mu \\
&= (\det \phi) (\operatorname{div} X) \mu + (X \cdot \det \phi) \mu \\
&= ((\det \phi) (\operatorname{div} X) + X \cdot \det \phi) \mu \\
\end{align*}
If $\phi$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, then pulling back both sides by $\phi^{-1}$ (noting that $(\phi^{-1})^* \mu = ((\det \phi)^{-1} \circ \phi^{-1}) \nu$) and clearing the common factors $\nu$leaves the identity
$$\boxed{\operatorname{div} Y = (\operatorname{div} X + X \cdot (\log \det \phi)) \circ \phi^{-1}}$$ of functions on $N$. In particular, if $\phi$ is an isomorphism of volume forms, i.e., if $\phi^* \nu = \mu$, then
$$\operatorname{div} Y = (\operatorname{div} X) \circ \phi^{-1} .$$
